# How to determine positive or negative definite of a bordered Hessian ?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I want to determine the minimization result I get using Lagrange Multiplier method is a local minimum by determining whether the Bordered Hessian is positive definite or negative definite.(Hopefully negative definite for a local minimum)

But since I have a system of 1000 variables, I am stuck with a 1000*1000 matrix to determine whether it is positive definite or negative definite.(this is all real numbers)

Is there any way to do it other than calculates all the eigenvalue ? 
Someone suggests a cholesky decomposition, but I failed to understand why.

Comment: since the number in first row and first column in Bordered Hessian is 0,Sylvester's criterion could not apply.

Comment: a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if it has a cholesky decomposition